# React <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"> куда вставить?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Куда и как правильно в React приложении вставить мета тег

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
```

Подозреваю, что там или либа отдельная должна быть или еще что-то.
Но мне нужно добиться эффекта, как если бы я на html страницу вставил этот мета тог, но у меня react приложение.

Comment: Прямо в index.html, в <head>, где и все мета-теги. Или в чем подвох?

Comment: @Макск я начал гуглить и нашел кучу разных либ под это дело, нашел какой-то helmet и много вопросов на стаке, где каждый ответ отличается от другого) Вот и запутался, подумал что такой вариант со вставкой в head что-то около костыля и в реакте есть более "правильные" подходы к этому. Общепринятые какие-то)

Answer (score 0):

В Реакте есть несколько способов как использовать мета теги:

1. С помощью react-document-meta. Устанавливаете расширение через терминал. Потом прописываете как jsx код и возвращаете как обычный елемент.
2. Есть похожее расширение как выше, оно называется react-meta-tags. Принцип работы такой же.
3. React Helmet. Одно из самых популярных расширений. Вот ссылка как использовать - [тут](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet)